# Как можно оптимизировать эту часть кода?Java,socket

Tags: java, сокет, swing, изображения

Я принимаю изображение и рисую его в окне но с каждым нарисованным изображением памяти жрёт всё больше и больше.При долгой работе вообще отказывает и выдаёт сломанную картинку.
Вот сам код:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VideoChannel {
BufferedImage img;
JFrame frame;
Graphics g;
boolean easy=true;
Bridge br;
Socket accep;
PrintWriter out;
    public VideoChannel(Socket accep,Bridge br,AdapterServer server) throws IOException{
        createFrame();
        server.isVideo = true;
        this.br = br;
        out = new PrintWriter(accep.getOutputStream());
        this.accep = accep;try{
        while(server.isVideo){
            g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(accep.getInputStream())),0,0,800,600,null);out.println("1");out.flush();}
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);disconnect();}
  disconnect();
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        System.out.println("Запущен видео канал");
      frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(800,600);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setTitle("Image");
   frame.setResizable(false);
   frame.setVisible(true);
    g = frame.getGraphics();
    }
    public void disconnect(){System.out.println("Выключен канал видео");br.VideosO();
    easy = false;
    frame.dispose();
    g.dispose();
    frame = null;
    g = null;
    img = null;
    try {accep.close();} catch (IOException ex) {}
    System.gc();

    }

}
```

Также после вызова функции disconnect() память не очищается и остаётся заполненной.

Comment: Закрывайте `InputStream` которые создаете `ImageIO.createImageInputStream`

Comment: Не срабатывает даже после закрытия InputStream память не очищаеться .

Comment: Вы не можете рисовать снова-и-снова в сломанную картинку.

Comment: И как тогда выводить в окно чтоб поверх прошлого не рисовать?